# Gruntjs: why compiled scss to empty file? using grunt-contrib-sass plugin

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I am trying to compile scss file using the grunt-contrib-sass plugin (with grunt v0.4.0). The compiled result is an empty css file. Below are the base.scss, Gruntfile.js and package.json files.

base.scss

```
$color: #000;

header{
color: $color;  
}
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    // Metadata.
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),       
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: { style: "expanded", trace: true },
            files: { "base.css": "base.scss" }
        }       
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

// Default task.
grunt.registerTask("default", [""]);
grunt.registerTask("sass--",["sass"]);
};
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "my_grunt",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "New to Grunt",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "test"
},
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "none"
},
"keywords": [
        "none"
],
"author": "none",
"license": "BSD",
"devDependencies": {
        "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.2.2"
}
}
```

Result:

Either I run the sass command "grunt sass" or "grunt sass--", the result is just an empty css file without any errors.

Your help is greatly appreciated

Niusaul

Comment: I tried this with the latest `sass` gem (3.2.7), copied/pasted your well prepared example, and it seems to work for me. Anything suspicious if you run `grunt sass --verbose`?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed Grunt globally, you'll either do that or add Grunt as a dependency. Otherwise Grunt won't work.

To install Grunt globally run `npm install -g grunt-cli` in your Terminal or add as a "devDependency":

```
"devDependencies": {
      "grunt": "0.4.x",
      "grunt-contrib-sass": "0.7.x",
   }
```

---

**Edit:**
While searching on Google about this problem, I stumpled upon a reported bug on Github from the same user where his problem is solved. Just for everyone who may experienced the same problem, this was his solution:

> The error is caused by the manual config that I've set in the Command
>   Processor (Windows registry), from which I've added an autorun to
>   change the default command prompt.